# IB Storyboard for App Extensions: iPad Icons Not Present, Sizes Don't Change, Orientation Not Working

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, ios-app-extension

I need to update a 3 year old iPhone-only, portrait only (NOT universal) camera/photo app that worked with iOS 8 that contains a Share extension that now (with 10.0???) crashes at times (but works many other times), and I'm trying to debug the issues and update to iOS 9.0.

The first issue I found and fixed was the lack of Privacy strings for access to the camera and photo library.

But I also found that the extension does not work with Photos on an iPad with layout issues (in the Simulator so far). As the docs say, extension targets must be made for iPhone/iPad and my build setting for the target extension are set to 1,2, and I use Auto Layout.

The storyboard, the Extension scene, a View Controller Scene, all view controllers, views and subviews all are set for Auto Layout as well as Safe Area Layout Guides, but the only devices shown in IB are iPhones with no iPads available, when selecting other devices no change is seen in size, and the iPhone is constrained to portrait mode.

I've tried setting the main app as Universal, allowing every orientation, building, and still no iPad icons in IB to test the UI for the extension (and trying to get Landscape mode in IB doesn't work either).

Is there a way to get IB to show and allow iPads/iPhones, particularly iPads, and change orientation during development for app extensions?

Answer (score 0):

Selecting "Use Trait Variations" made the iPad icons appear.